# Oracle Materialized views

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I have a scenario as below.

a) Table A with 10 columns of which 3 columns form a composite primary key.

b) A MV is created on top of table A.(Direct select query from table A)

c) MV logs are created on top of table A and MV is configured for fast refresh

Now i need to remove 1 column from the primary key combination so that i will still have 10 columns in my table A but only 2 columns form the composite primary key.

How should i handle my MV on top of the table? Should i recreate the MV and MVLogs?